# Tensorflow Binary Error Python vs Go

Tags: python, go, tensorflow

I'm not sure if the way i installed the tensorflow on my laptop is correct or not and still trying to figure out some of the issues.

Initially i installed Tensorflow on my Mac book pro and have no luck there (will come to that later) then i installed on a vagrant box using a ubuntu 16.04 image.

```
(tensorflow) ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Hello, TensorFlow!
>>> 
(tensorflow) ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ go run testing_tensor.go 
2017-11-22 15:50:43.747754: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
Hello from TensorFlow version 1.4.0
```

Not sure how different this is from using a python library and go library and how can i identify if the tensorflow is using the cpu instead gpu?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow will tell you what device a session is using if you create the session with the `log_device_placement` option set to true:

```
conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=conf)
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: Hi i get the following when i tried the above code `>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, Tensorflow!')
>>> conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=conf)
Device mapping: no known devices.
2017-11-22 19:19:26.655582: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:299] Device mapping:

>>> print(sess.run(hello))`

Comment: That tells you that the session is running on the CPU, not the GPU. You can check if TensorFlow knows the GPU is there by calling `device_lib.list_local_devices()`. But first, you need to import `device_lib` with `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib`.

Comment: I tried it and i get the following `>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> device_lib.list_local_devices()
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13755107272709323438
]` so this means i'm using the cpu but not gpu and i'm still confused why go compiler complains that the cpu don't support the binary

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the "Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX" message. That's just a warning that tells you that TensorFlow won't use your CPU's advanced capabilities. If you want to use these capabilities, you need to build TensorFlow from source code.

Comment: even if its a warning i assume i can use all basic tensorflow stuff right ?

Comment: Right. You can use the entire TensorFlow API, but it will run faster if you build the package from source. You can suppress the warning by setting the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to 3.

Comment: Yes, and it's very easy for Linux systems. The directions are at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux.